# Bootstrap Tabbed Content Not Hiding Properly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap tab field working properly and I'm having some difficulties.

The content is tabbing between each div, however what I'm running into is that the content from each tab is being displayed on the page, only hidden. So whenever one of the tabs is clicked all it does is hides the content above, and unhides the content below it instead of switching properly.

In the screenshot below you can see the content from the `#android-screenshots` tab showing up beneath the content in the `#ios-screenshots` tab causing a large amount of unneeded blank space.

[image: Rendered Content]

Here is what my markup looks like:

```
<div id="mobile-splash-faq-screenshots" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
        <!-- Nav tabs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
          <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#ios-screenshots" aria-controls="ios-screenshots" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">iOS Screenshots</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#android-screenshots" aria-controls="android-screenshots" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Android Screenshots</a></li>
          <li role="presentation"><a href="#faq" aria-controls="faq" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">FAQ</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Tab panes -->
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div class="container">
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active fade in" id="ios-screenshots">
              <div class="screenshots">

                <p class="excerpt text-center">Screenshots taken on an iPhone 4S.</p>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/ios_screenshot_01.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/ios_screenshot_02.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/ios_screenshot_03.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/ios_screenshot_02.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/ios_screenshot_03.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/ios_screenshot_01.png" />
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>

            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="android-screenshots">
              <div class="screenshots">

                <p class="excerpt text-center">Screenshots taken on a Google Nexus 6.</p>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/android_screenshot_01.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/android_screenshot_02.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/android_screenshot_03.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/android_screenshot_04.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/android_screenshot_01.png" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-4">
                  <img class="img-responsive" src="${contextRoot}/resources/assets/img/mobile-splash/android_screenshot_01.png" />
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>

            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="faq">

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is what my Javascript looks like:

```
(function($) {

  $('.nav-tabs a').on('click', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).tab('show');
 });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 7):

Managed to resolve this by adding the following CSS:

```
  .tab-pane:not(.active) {
      display: none;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved me so much time! Bootstrap seems to have a bug with tabs.